# declare a variable of UIIMage+AFNetWorking

Tags: iphone, variable-declaration

I am downloading an image from a url using `UIImage+AFNetworking`. How can I declare a variable of type `UIImage+AFNetworking`? Should it be

```
UIImage+AFNetworking *myRequest  = [[ UIImage+AFNetworking....] ];
```

I know it does not make sense when we have a `+` sign in the middle. Please advice me if you know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is only a category; by including the headerfile into your class, it will automatically extend the UIImage class with the AFNetworking functionality.

Means:

```
UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[myImage replaceMeWithTheRightMethodCall];
```

Best,
Christian

Comment: +1 yup - I'm guessing the OP wants to use something from this header. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h

Comment: I just imported AFNetWorking in myClass. m. After creating an img , I did *** [myImg  setImageWithURL:myUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-stam.png"]];**** I got an erro such that "Receiver type UIImage for instance message does not declare a method with selector""setImageWithURL:placeholder****. Did I miss something

Comment: just tried imported "UIImageView+AFNetWorking.h", still got a same error